# « Comparable à » ou « comparable avec »

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

Aujourd'hui, j'ai eu des difficultés en voulant m'exprimer. Je ne savais pas si je devrais dire *comparable à* (comparable aux) ou *comparable avec*.

C'est la traduction de « comparable to » que je souhaiterais exprimer.

Answer (score 3):

Le *comparable* anglais correspond souvent au *comparable* français. D'autres adjectifs peuvent parfois être plus pertinents pour le traduire.

Comparable signifie en mathématiques apte à être comparé, mais le sens commun est « qui ne présente pas de grosses différences », étymologiquement : *que l'on peut rendre égal (pair) avec*.

On peut très bien comparer la masse du Soleil à celle d'une pomme, pourtant on dira toujours que leurs masses respectives ne sont pas comparables. En revanche, on dira que la masse de la Terre est comparable à celle de Mars.

> Cet immense obélisque noir ainsi isolé entre les deux nappes blanches du ciel et de la rivière, fort large en cet endroit, fit à dom Claude un effet singulier, **comparable à** ce qu’éprouverait un homme qui, couché à terre sur le dos au pied du clocher de Strasbourg, regarderait l’énorme aiguille s’enfoncer au-dessus de sa tête dans les pénombres du crépuscule. Victor Hugo, *Notre Dame de Paris*, 1831.

Il existe de nombreux adjectifs partageant le même sens, ou très proches, et on peut noter qu'ils utilisent tous exclusivement *à* :

- similaire à
- semblable à
- équivalent à
- analogue à
- identique à
- pareil à
- homologue à
- assimilé à
- égal à
- ressemblant à

Par cohérence, il paraît donc plus logique d'utiliser *comparable à*, et c'est bien l'usage largement prédominant :

[image]

Un adjectif courant qui utilise *avec* a un sens différent :

- compatible avec (étymologiquement *qui peut souffrir, endurer avec*).

Answer (score -1):

La question est plaisante dans la mesure où le préfixe (*com*) signifie *avec*.

*Comparable avec* pourrait donc être vu pléonastique... mais... il se trouve admis dans la meilleure des langues.

Grevisse admet que *"la distinction entre comparer avec et comparer à n'est pas toujours bien nette"*.

Pour Littré, on préfère *comparer à* et conséquemment *comparable à* quand il s'agit de trouver un rapport d'égalité.
Et *comparer avec* et conséquemment *comparable avec* quand on confronte, qu'on recherche les ressemblances et les dissemblances.

Mais on trouverait de nombreux contre-exemples dans la littérature.